# Getting File not found exception on reading a file in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

File located at `/opt/apps/workspace/build32/target/site/result.html` on the Linux worker node. The build is running under `/opt/apps/workspace/build32` folder. Below is the code snippet I am using.

```
if (fileExists("/opt/apps/workspace/build32/target/site/result.html")) {
  echo "result.html file exist"
}
else {
  echo " File does not exist"
}
def file = new File("/opt/apps/workspace/build32/target/site/result.html").collect{it}
def index = file.findIndexOf{ it ==~ /.*Result.*/ }
echo "file[index]"
```

Output:

```
Running in /opt/apps/workspace/build32. 
[pipeline] result.html file exist 
[pipeline] build status UNSTABLE build message there was an error on stage Test, result.html (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Output:  
Running in /opt/apps/workspace/build32.  
[pipeline]  
[pipeline]  
result.html file exist  
[pipeline]   
build status UNSTABLE build message there was an error on stage Test, result.html (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Problem

You need to be aware that running any arbitrary Groovy (or Java) code always gets executed on your Jenkins master, no matter which worker node executes the code in your pipeline. Jenkins Pipeline steps are an exception to this rule, and they get executed on the current worker node. That is why:

```
fileExists("/opt/apps/workspace/build32/target/site/result.html")
```

prints expected output because `fileExists` is a standard Jenkins Pipeline step, and thus it gets executed on the worker node that creates the file in its workspace.
It's worth mentioning that pipeline steps can be used inside either `steps { }` block or inside the `script { }` block of the declarative pipeline, or directly in the scripted pipeline code.

When you call:

```
def file = new File("/opt/apps/workspace/build32/target/site/result.html").collect{it}
```

you get the error because `new File(...)` gets executed on the Jenkins master node, and its workspace does not contain the file that was created in the workspace of the worker node.

### Solution

Instead of executing an arbitrary Groovy code, you can use [`readFile` pipeline step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) - a step that will read the file using the current worker node and its workspace. You can access files inside the workspace using a relative path, so something like this should read the contents of the file:

```
def file = readFile(file: 'target/site/result.html')
```

Keep in mind, that the `readFile` step returns the contents of the file as a single `String`, so if you want to process it line by line, you might have to do something like this:

```
def lines = readFile(file: 'target/site/result.html').readLines()
```

The following code will produce a `List<String>` of lines from the file. Depending on your Jenkins configuration, the `String.readLines()` method might require whitelisting before you can use it in your Jenkins pipeline code.

Comment: Thank you @Szymon Stepnaik for the detailed explanation. I was trying with readFile but got struck. First place I have to read the file then search for a string "Result" in the file and then print 3rd line from the match. Can you please suggest how can I do that using readFile.

Comment: When you read the text of the file using `readFile`, you can turn it into a list using `readLines()` or even `split('\n')`. Then you can call `findIndexOf { it =~ /Result/ }` on that list to get the index of the line that contains `Result` in it. It may happen that either `readLines` or `split` methods do require whitelisting - if this is the case, you will get an error in the pipeline log with a link to the admin page where you can allow using the method in your pipeline code. When you re-run it, you should get the result.

Comment: I am having a similar problem too. I wrote a groovy method which is at the top of my scripted pipeline and the method reads an xml file from the workspace.It works pretty well when i am running on the master node. Now, my jenkins jobs are ran in a kubernetes pod and based on what you just explained, it seems the groovy method can't find the files since it is executing the code in the master node. Do you know how i can solve this problem @SzymonStepniak ? without using pipeline steps

Comment: The only way to read the file from the current workspace is to use `readFile` pipeline step. Check this documentation page on accessing pipeline steps in the shared library - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps It's not exactly the same case as yours, but you can do a similar thing as it is described for the `Utilities.mvn(script,args)` method in the doc page I mentioned earlier.